# input with dynamic default value not editable

Tags: reactjs, input

I have a field in my react app whose value can be dynamic,
If I click "Create new", its default value is "", and if I click an item from a table, it populates the input field with the corresponding value.

However, when I try to add another text to the non-empty input field, the value is not changing.

Here's my input field:

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="John" onChange={e => handleInputChange(e.target.value, "firstname")} value={selectedItem && selectedItem.client?.firstname }/>
```

The `selectedItem`'s value is deconstructed from a props called `selectedEvent`, I made it like this since props are immutable and I thought that was the problem.

**EDITED**

I even removed the `onChange` and replace the dynamic value with a static value. But its not changing at all.

**EDIT**

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="John" value="Hello world" onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)}/>
```

I noticed, when I log the onChange result, it displays the **Hello world** and whatever key you press, be it backspace or any letters, it only removes or add 1 Letter.

For example:
Default value: **Hello world**, when I type asdasd it logs **Hello worlda**

and when I press backspace, it logs **Hello worl**

Comment: Can I ask you to provide a bit more context? I am interested in `selectedItem` and `handleInputChange`. Would be best if you'd provide component or part of code reproducable in JsFiddle.

Comment: @Nectos,  I added an edit,

Comment: Still nothing much to grasp on. Could you try using local state for value? `value={this.state.value}` then withing handler do a `setState`. Or if this is hooks, go for `useState` hook.

Comment: For your second Post Edit: It is expected behaviour because value does not actually change.

Comment: Oh I get it, what a dumb mistake. thanks man

Comment: No problem. Is there any more help needed? Did you try using state?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `value` option inside `input` component.
use `useRef` hook to update value of input dynamically.
You can use like this:

```
const inputRef = useRef();

useEffect(()=>{
inputRef.current.value = "Something else!";
},[])

<input ref={inputRef}/>
```

I hope It will help you.